# Can I power seven 54W LED light strips from a 400W supply?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

I have ws2812b 60 LED/meter and a 400W/80A power supply.  Is it fair to say that my power supply is 'capable of supplying' up to 400W of power and not 'pushing' all 400W of power?  My understanding is that the circuit components will 'draw' (pull) only the amount of power they need from that great ocean of 400W of available power. Therefore if my 5m addressable ws2812b LED light strip draws total of 54W (60mA * 3V * 300 LEDs = 54W), then I can power up to 7 such strips on this same 400W power supply?

Comment: 7 * 54 = 378    ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  If you connect one 54 watt strip, it will draw 54 watts through the power supply.  If you connect seven strips, they'll draw 378 watts.